# System.Xml.XmlException: „The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.”

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I wanna to create in my xml something like this:

```
<root>
  <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  </xsd:schema>
</root>
```

My code looks like this right now:

```
XElement rootElement = new XElement("root");
XDeclaration xDeclaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "true");
XElement xdsElement = new XElement("xsd:schema"); // Exception there!
```

And my exception:

> System.Xml.XmlException: „The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A,
> cannot be included in a name.”

How to awoid this exception, maybe there is some kind of generator for that phrases?

Comment: The string before the colon is the namespace and the tag name is after the colon.  The Net library does not allow the namespace to be entered as part of the tagname.

Comment: Try `XNamespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` and then `new XElement(xsd + "schema");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @juharr said in the comments, you need to define it as XNamespace first, here's how:

```
var ns_xsd = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
var ns_msdata = XNamespace.Get("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata");

var root = new XElement("root", 
    new XElement(ns_xsd + "schema", 
        new XAttribute("id", "root"), 
        new XAttribute("xmlns", ""), 
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", ns_xsd),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "msdata", ns_msdata),
        new XAttribute(ns_msdata + "IsDataSet", "true")));
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how to deal with this one: new XAttribute("msdata:IsDataSet", "true")

Comment: @Obyi the logic is the same, you need to declare it as a namespace using msdata's Uri, I made an edit showing how